# Trying to Solve a Vehicle Routing Problem with time windows

Tags: cplex

i'm trying to solve a VRPWT for a university work and i'm having some troubles, CPLEX keeps teeling me that it is infeasible.

Can someone please check my code to see what i've been missing?

```
int n=...;
range cliente=0..n+1;
int nveiculos=...;
range K=1..nveiculos;

tuple edge {
    int i;
    int j;
    int z;
}

{edge} edges = {<i,j,z> | i,j in cliente : i!=j && i!=6 && j!=0 , z in K};

int custo[edges]=...;
int d[cliente]=...;

int t[edges]=...;
float a[cliente]=...;
float b[cliente]=...;
float q[K]=...;


dvar boolean x[edges];
dvar int s[cliente][K];



minimize sum(j in edges) sum(i in edges) custo[i]*x[j];



subject to {

    forall(k in K){
     sum( j in cliente: j!=0) x[<0,j,k>] ==1;
}



forall(k in K)
forall(p in cliente: p!=6 ){ 
      sum( h in cliente: h!=p && h!=0) x[<p,h,k>]==1; }


forall(k in K){
      sum(i in cliente) sum(j in cliente: i!=j && i!=6 && j!=0, k in K) d[i]* x[<i,j,k>] <=q[k];
 }    


        forall(k in K)
        forall(h in cliente: h!=0){
      sum(i in cliente: i!=h && i!=6) x[<i,h,k>] == sum(j in cliente: j!=h && h!=6 && j!=0) x[<h,j,k>];
}    



forall(k in K){
      sum(i in cliente: i!=6) x[<i,6,k>] ==1;

 }
        forall(k in K)
        forall(i in cliente){
      a[i]<= s[i][k]<=b[i];
}

    forall(k in K)
    forall(i,j in cliente: i!=j && i!=6 && j!=0)
      s[i][k]+t[<i,j,k>]- 1000*(1-x[<i,j,k>]) <= s[j][k]; 

}
```

I'm using 2 vehicles (nveiculos) and 5 clients, used a range for clients to add the home depot and the last depot. a and b stands for the open time of the client and b for the closing time. d is the demand of each client and q is the vehicle capacity. the s variable stands for the time the vehicle arrives at the client.

I already have much simple solutions, though it does not match the algorithm in the article im based on and i'm a little bit stubborn  and wanted to get my way around this problem.

It would be awesome if someone could help me.
Best regards

Comment: Do you have to use CPLEX? Generally mathematical programming techniques don't scale to large VRP sizes (e.g. with hundreds or thousands of jobs), unless you combine them with some kind of matheuristic (e.g. fix most of the solution and use CPLEX to solve just a small part of the solution at a time). Combinations of local search heuristics together with controlling metaheuristics appear to be the most popular/successfull solutions in the research papers.